# $f(x,y)=(x^3-3xy^2,3x^2y-y^3)$ is a local diffeomorphism, but not a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Show that the map $f\colon \mathbb R^2\backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb R^2\backslash\{0\}$ given by $f(x,y)=(x^3-3xy^2,3x^2y-y^3)$ is a local diffeomorphism, but not a (global) diffeomorphism.

---

It is a local diffeomorphism as one can show using the inverse function theorem. Indeed
$$ df_{(x,y)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3x^2-3y^2& -6xy \\
6xy& 3x^2-3y^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Its determinant is $(3x^2-3y^2)^2+36x^2y^2\neq 0$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$.

To show that it is not a diffeomorphism, I tried to show that it fails to be injective. Trying to finding distinct points giving same $f$ was not fruitful. Any idea of how to proceed from there!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Then the map is $z \mapsto z^3$. Can you show it's not injective from here?

Comment: If $f(x,y)=(z,t)$, then $z+it=(x+iy)^3$, which lets you find the triplets that map into the same point (using cubic roots of unity).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Yes. Thanks!

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks!

Comment: @ahmd092 Then you should write an answer to your own question.